# Struct com JSON no C++

Tags: json, c++, struct

Estou tendo problemas para inflar uma struct utilizando um arquivo JSON, na realidade eu não sei como fazer isso, andei pesquisando sobre a biblioteca JsonCpp, mas não obtive sucesso.

Segue um exemplo simples do meu código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Itens{
    int id, tipo, valor;
};

int main() {

    funcaoEncherStruct();

    return 0;
}

void funcaoEncherStruct(){
    //Segue função aqui
}
```

Arquivo JSON:

```
{
    "Itens": {
        "Produto1": {
            "id": 1,
            "tipo": 1,
            "valor": 20,
        },
        "Produto2": {
            "id": 2,
            "tipo": 3,
            "valor": 33,
        },
        "Produto3": {
            "id": 3,
            "tipo": 6,
            "valor": 60,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade não é possível "inflar" uma struct já que esse termo define uma estrutura de dados ou tipo de dados. O que você vai querer fazer é encher um container com objetos do tipo da sua struct. Outra coisa... vai ser complicado fazer o que você  quer com esse arquivo json. O arquivo define um array de Itens de três tipos, Produto1, 2 e 3, acho que seria mais simples:

```
{ "Itens": 
  [
    { "id": 1, "tipo": 1, "valor": 20, }, 
    { "id": 2, "tipo": 3, "valor": 33, }, 
    { "id": 3, "tipo": 6, "valor": 60, } 
  ]
}
```

Se puder ser esse json então fica fácil popular um container do tipo vector com objetos do tipo da sua struct:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

using namespace std; 

struct Item{ int id, tipo, valor; }; 

int main() { 
  vector<Item> containeritens;

  ifstream ifs("Arquivo.json");
  Json::Reader reader; 
  Json::Value obj;

  reader.parse(ifs, obj); 

  const Json::Value& itens = obj["Itens"]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < itens.size(); i++).{
    Item item;
    item.id = itens[i]["id"].asUInt();
    item.tipo = itens[i]["tipo"].asUInt();
    item.valor = itens[i]["valor"].asUInt();

    contairnerItens.pushback(item);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Entendi, consegui abrir um pouco meus olhos pra isso, quando eu digo inflar uma struct eu digo preenche-la, entende? Tentei compilar o código e corri atrás de alguma solução, mas achei algumas incompletas ou técnicas de mais, o " Json::Reader " não está depreciado? Não seria: "Json::CharReaderBuilder", como eu faço um parse com essa propriedade?

Comment: Mas não tem como preencher uma struct, a struct só define o tipo de dados entende?

Comment: Eu entendo, já resolvi também essa charada, utilizei outra biblioteca na qual a documentação era mais organizada, mas obrigado pela ajuda!